# Programmatically set IE8 in Private Browsing mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Dear all, I want to set IE8 to private browsing mode once a user logs in to my javascript application. Programmatically. Possible?

Comment: I doubt it. Why, what is your end goal with this?

Comment: If you could set private browsing to 'on' you could also set it to 'off'.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the best you can do is offer simple directions to opening the webpage in [InPrivate Browsing](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie-9/features/in-private) mode from an information section on the login page. Probably offer the webpage's link ready to copy too because you can't simply right-click a link and open it in InPrivate from IE8/9.

While you're at it, maybe offering similar directions for the browser the visitor is using would be a more thorough solution to the problem.